# using addition in a MySQL table row?

Tags: php, mysql

How to update value  "100"  If the  $id duplicate by adding +100 to it  so the total will be 200 in the level 
here is my INSERT statement

```
  INSERT INTO users (id, name, level) VALUES ($id, 'name', 100 )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the trick for you (I am assuming that id is a unique field and can be used to identify the correct row to update):

```
$query="INSERT INTO 
users (id, name, level) 
VALUES ($id, 'name', 100 ) 
on duplicate key 
    update set level=level+100";
```

Answer (score 0):

Since UPDATE is MySQL specific the more generic way is to do 
`INSERT INTO users (id,name,level) VALUES ($id, 'name', 100)
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE level = level + VALUES(level)`

See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/de/insert-on-duplicate.html
AFAIK this is more generally applicable then only on MySQL.